# get value from returned xml received on ajax success

Tags: ajax, jquery, xml-parsing

I have made an ajax call which returns me some xml in my success function.something like this:

```
<grid row_count="39">
  <item>
     <id>343</id>
     <publickey>e9a515f9-44ac-4af9-b4b2-c30dd366ac83</publickey>
     <name><![CDATA[repeater dsds]]></name>
     <description />
     <subject />
     <templatetype>16</templatetype>
     <socialmediatype>0</socialmediatype>
     <trackingmediaid />
     <companyid>226</companyid>
     <createdon>3/14/2013 12:15:03 PM</createdon>
     <updatedon>
```

I want to get the value of row_count present in grid tag.i am not at all familiar with xml.any help would be great.
Thanks...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dataType is set to xml, jQuery will parse it for you, otherwise run `$.parseXML` and use DOM traversal methods the regular way:

```
var xml = $.parseXML(data_from_ajax);

var row_count = $(xml).filter('grid').attr('row_count');
```

In your string above neither `item` nor `grid` is properly closed, and that will cause issues if that is how the original string is as well. You also need to use either `find()` or `filter()` depending on where `grid` occurs in the string ?

Comment: Then you need to start somewhere, like opening the console (F12) and doing `console.log( $(xml).filter('grid')[0] )` and see if that returns an element, and elements must be closed properly ?